# mediaelement.js: Loop icon/image doesn't appear

Tags: mediaelement.js

The loop icon/image doesn't appear in the example on http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=loop and I can't get it to appear for my own project either. The function works perfectly fine, just the icon doesn't appear (shows blank space). Checked all the css and appears fine. Required for IE9 but doesn't seem to work with any browser.